# How to implement two tabs using linear-gradient

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

There are two tabs, and the background-color of each tab is linear, and both of them have border-radius. They looks like below:

[image]

[image]

each tab's background is

```
linear-gradient(to right, #FF7243, #FF563E);
```

the code is like this:

```css
.tab-container {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
}

.tab-item {
  flex: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF7243, #FF563E);
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-container">
  <div class="tab-item"></div>
  <div class="tab-item"></div>
</div>
```

Because of the border-radius, there will be blank between two tabs, so how to make the blank part's background color change with the tab switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make both tabs to overlap like below. You can also remove the radius when it's not needed.

```css
.tab-container {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  margin:10px;
}

.tab-item {
  flex: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF7243, #FF563E);
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.tab-item:first-child {
  margin-right:-10px;
}

.active {
 z-index:1; /*active always on the top*/
  background: linear-gradient(to right, purple, blue);
}
/*when the first child is not active no need top-right radius*/
:not(.active):first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
/*when the last child is not active no need top-left radius*/
:not(.active):last-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-container">
  <div class="tab-item active"></div>
  <div class="tab-item"></div>
</div>
<div class="tab-container">
  <div class="tab-item"></div>
  <div class="tab-item active"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.tab-container { width: 200px; display: flex; height: 40px; } .tab-item { flex: 1; background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF7243, #FF563E); border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-top-left-radius: 10px }

<div class="tab-container"> <div class="tab-item"></div> <div class="tab-item"></div>
```